# How Do I Find my /Mods folder in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-forge

SO, I've been reading all these guides for Forge that tell me to put the mods in my .minecraft/mods folder. But my .minecraft folder dosen't have a /mods folder. what do I do about that?

Answer (score 0):

When you install forge and run the forge build initially it *should* create the /mods folder automatically. If it is not generated then you can just make one but make sure it is named "mods" without the quotes.